# How to simulate new data inside the function predict?

Tags: r, lapply, predict, lda

I'm working with lda (linear discrminant analysis) in which I have 136 individuals, 1 categorical variable (with 3 categories) and 50 variables to analyze.
Up to the step of prediction of the new indviduals, I don't know how to proceed to recreate new samples to the already existing df

With the example database it would be like:

```
library(MASS)
res <- lda(Species ~ . , iris)
res

# new data to predict

prednew <- predict(res, newdata=data.frame(Sepal.Length=5, Sepal.Width=3, Petal.Length=2.5, Petal.Width=0.3))
```

As you can see is easy here because there are 4 variables, and typing the simulated data is  possible. I would like to simulate some data & if it is possible make it similar to the already existing (I provide some nonsense unsuccesful code to show what I try to achieve)

```
#ldat is my dataframe
str(ldat)
'data.frame':   136 obs. of  51 variables:

# some code I tried to run with some made-up data
prednew <- predict(model1, newdata = data.frame(lapply(1:ncol(ldat[,2:51]), mutate(geny = rnorm(n = 1, mean = 1.5, sd = 0.3)))))

#trying to make it similar to the whole database
prednew <- predict(model1, newdata = data.frame(lapply(1:ncol(ldat[,2:51]), mutate(geny = rnorm(n = 1, mean = mean(ldat[,2:51]), sd = sd(ldat[,2:51]))))))
```

Comment: Do do you just want to sample independently from all the columns assuming a normal distribution? You could do something like `ndata <- lapply(iris[,-5], function(x) rnorm(1, mean(x), sd(x))); predict(res, newdata=ndata)` using `iris`. If you are just predicting one value it might make more sense just to use the mean rather than a random draw. But both methods ignore any correlation so might not be truly representative.

Comment: How would you do it if you intended to add  n = 20 ? I'm not sure if I'm getting what you trying to say? In fact, the code your taking the mean. If it is about new sample to predict, that it would be correlated with the existing one? I'm rigging the numbers. How would you simulate it instead?

Comment: If you want simulation advice, that's a statistical question and would be better asked at [stats.se]. I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish with these random predictions in the first place. What sort of interpretation do you want these values to have?

Comment: Just what you did. I didn't know how to add new data, and I was trying in one step. I am just trying with the analysis and the code of lda (it's new to me). The preanalysis is to get familiarised with the output. Thanks